# Send Attachments with Amazon-SES

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm searching for an working C# example to send attachments with Amazon-SES.

After reading that [Amazon-SES](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/07/amazon-simple-email-service-now-supports-attachments.html) now supports sending attachments I was searching for an C# example but was unable to find one.

Answer (score 29):

I think that using [AWS SDK for .NET](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net) and [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) is very easy and clean solution. You can send e-mails with attachments via SES API (instead of SMTP).

You can write MimeMessage directly to MemoryStream and then use it with SES SendRawEmail:

```
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using MimeKit;

private static BodyBuilder GetMessageBody()
{
    var body = new BodyBuilder()
    {
        HtmlBody = @"<p>Amazon SES Test body</p>",
        TextBody = "Amazon SES Test body",
    };
    body.Attachments.Add(@"c:\attachment.txt");
    return body;
}

private static MimeMessage GetMessage()
{
    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Foo Bar", "foo@bar.com"));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(string.Empty, "foobar@example.com"));
    message.Subject = "Amazon SES Test";
    message.Body = GetMessageBody().ToMessageBody();
    return message;
}

private static MemoryStream GetMessageStream()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    GetMessage().WriteTo(stream);
    return stream;
}

private void SendEmails()
{
    var credentals = new BasicAWSCredentials("<aws-access-key>", "<aws-secret-key>");

    using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentals, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
    {
        var sendRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest { RawMessage = new RawMessage(GetMessageStream()) };
        try
        {
            var response = client.SendRawEmail(sendRequest);
            Console.WriteLine("The email was sent successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
            Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
public Boolean SendRawEmail(String from, String to, String cc, String Subject, String text, String html, String replyTo, string attachPath)
    {
        AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);

        List<String> toAddresses = to.Replace(", ", ",").Split(',').ToList();

        foreach (String toAddress in toAddresses)
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
        }

        List<String> ccAddresses = cc.Replace(", ", ",").Split(',').Where(y => y != "").ToList();

        foreach (String ccAddress in ccAddresses)
        {
            mailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccAddress));
        }

        mailMessage.Subject = Subject;
        mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        if (replyTo != null)
        {
            mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(replyTo));
        }

        if (text != null)
        {
            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
        }

        if (html != null)
        {
            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
        }

        if (attachPath.Trim() != "")
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(attachPath))
            {
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment objAttach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachPath);
                objAttach.ContentType = new ContentType("application/octet-stream"); 
                System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition disposition = objAttach.ContentDisposition;
                disposition.DispositionType = "attachment";
                disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(attachPath);
                disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(attachPath);
                disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(attachPath);
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(objAttach);
            }
        }

        RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage();

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(mailMessage))
        {
            rawMessage.WithData(memoryStream);
        }

        SendRawEmailRequest request = new SendRawEmailRequest();
        request.WithRawMessage(rawMessage);

        request.WithDestinations(toAddresses);
        request.WithSource(from);

        AmazonSimpleEmailService ses = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AccessKeyId"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SecretKeyId"));

        try
        {
            SendRawEmailResponse response = ses.SendRawEmail(request);
            SendRawEmailResult result = response.SendRawEmailResult;
            return true;
        }
        catch (AmazonSimpleEmailServiceException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static MemoryStream ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(MailMessage message)
    {
        Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
        Type mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
        MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream();
        ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
        object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { fileStream });
        MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        sendMethod.Invoke(message, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true }, null);
        MethodInfo closeMethod = mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new object[] { }, null);
        return fileStream;
    }
```

Found that [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=325690&#295303)

Update: A method signature has changed in .NET 4.5, which breaks the above:
[Getting System.Net.Mail.MailMessage as a MemoryStream in .NET 4.5 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595440/getting-system-net-mail-mailmessage-as-a-memorystream-in-net-4-5-beta)

Comment: If your project is using .NET Framework 3.5, this would be the only working solution. MimeKit recent releases does not support .NET Framework 3.5

Answer (score 6):

This is a very simple implementation using MimeKit

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
using MimeKit;
using System.IO;

namespace SendEmailWithAttachments
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Remember to enter your (AWSAccessKeyID, AWSSecretAccessKey) if not using and IAM User with credentials assigned to your instance and your RegionEndpoint
        using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient("YourAWSAccessKeyID", "YourAWSSecretAccessKey", RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        using (var messageStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            var builder = new BodyBuilder() { TextBody = "Hello World" };

            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("FROMADDRESS@TEST.COM"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("TOADDRESS@TEST.COM"));
            message.Subject = "Hello World";

            //I'm using the stream method, but you don't have to.
            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@"Attachment1.pdf", FileMode.Open)) builder.Attachments.Add("Attachment1.pdf", stream);
            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@"Attachment2.pdf", FileMode.Open)) builder.Attachments.Add("Attachment2.pdf", stream);

            message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
            message.WriteTo(messageStream);

            var request = new SendRawEmailRequest()
            {
                RawMessage = new RawMessage() { Data = messageStream }
            };

            client.SendRawEmail(request);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have the code in my repository https://github.com/gianluis90/amazon-send-email

Answer (score 1):

You can setup IIS SMTP to relay through SES as well.

You need to install [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html) and [set it up](https://gist.github.com/3236880)

Then you can just set the IIS SMTP *Smart Host* and some other options and it will relay your email through SES.

Instructions from above linked gist:

Instructions taken from [Amazon's docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SMTP.MTAs.SecureTunnel.html) and modified as necessary.

### 1. Install *stunnel*:

- Download from *stunnel's* [download page](http://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html)
- Run installer w/ default options, create self signed cert by answering questions
- Open the `c:\program files (x86)\stunnel\stunnel.conf` file in notepad
- Clear all the server configs (under `Example SSL server mode services` section, won't have a `client = yes` line)
- Create a new client config:

> [smtp-tls-wrapper]
>   accept = 127.0.0.1:2525
>   client = yes
>   connect = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465

- Start `stunnel.exe` and ensure no errors are reported (you will get a little systray icon)
- If it succeeds you can optionally install as a service, by running `stunnel.exe -install` at command line (note this installs the service but doesn't start it, so start it)
- Test the connection, at cmd line run `telnet localhost 2525` and you should see an SMTP response from Amazon's server (if telnet isn't installed, add the feature in *Server Manager / Features / Add Feature*)

### 2. Configure IIS SMTP

- Set Smart Host as `[127.0.0.1]` (include the brackets)
- In the **Outbound Connections** section, set outgoing port to `2525` (like the stunnel.conf file)
- In the **Outbound Security** section, set authentication information to your Amazon SMTP credentials, set it to basic authentication (**NOTE:** DO NOT CHECK THE TLS CHECKBOX)

Comment: I would only use this setup if you couldn't just change your code to send directly through SES or were using a system that didn't support the code option (see http://tekaris.com/blog/2012/07/25/sending-email-through-aws-ses/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it's the only resource I've been able to find on the subject.  I would love a better answer to this question, too.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/

It states how to use it, but is very cryptic, at least to me.

Any better guides out there?

Answer (score 0):

I also need help with this, but so far I've found you need to send a multipart MIME message, with the attachment encoded in base64.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow the instructions on [this link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SendingEmail.Raw.html). Amazon doesn't let you add attachments or other more complicated message types (iCalendar events). Essentially you need to handcraft the message body by string building and manipulation.

Currently I do this for iCalendar format emails on a legacy system. It's a bit of a pain in the ass, but if you read RFC 2822, it tells you pretty clearly what the format is. Special things to pay attention to:

- Base64 encoding of the data
- MIME types
- Make sure your multipart boundaries match up (and are unique)
- Finicky problems with the number of line breaks (\n) after certain lines

Best of luck. I don't know if there is an open library that will do this sort of thing for you in C#. If you can find one then try use it, because dealing with the intricacies of the RFC should have a medical notice for increased blood pressure and hair loss.